# Find value that is two characters different

Tags: excel, search, find, lookup

Can anyone help i have a spreadsheet that has item codes in the same column and i need to find an item code that is just two charscters diffetent to the first.
I.e. i know which row dftca0004 is and need to search for the row that contains dftea0004. Both item codes are in the same column.

Thanks in advance

Comment: think Google could solve this quickly, but is it always 2 letters, and are they always `ca` to `ea`? Your question could be improved a bit and some examples of what you have tried would be nice.

Comment: I have searched excel but i am only pretty new to this type of spreadsheeting. Yes the only difference is one is a carton code i.e. dtifca0004 and the corresponding contents are dtifea0004. Where the first and last four letters are different for each product.

Comment: so what is always the same cause i only se `ca` change to `ea`?

Comment: Yes that is the only difference between the two item codes for that product but it needs to search through hundreds of finished products i.e. with ca to find its matching packet i.e. with ea. 
So each finished product is a ****ca**** with a corresponding packet ****ea****. But the **** at the front and back differ for each finished product.

Answer (score 0):

When all the values are in the A Column and dtifca0004 is in cell A1, the following formula will return the rownumber of dtifea0004. This formula will work when the formats are ****c***** and ****e*****

```
=MATCH(REPLACE(A1,5,1,"e"),A:A)
```

Comment: Will it also work if the value isn't in cell a1. My equation looks up the ××××c×××× but need it to find the ××××e×××× the first ××××c×××× location isnt known

Comment: What does your equation that looks up the ****c***** look like?

Comment: this looks up the ****c**** value that is in a fixed cell $t$3 and it returns a value from a packaging worksheet from the corresponding row containing ****c****.  I have another section that needs the same information about the corresponding ****e****.                 
 =+IF($T$3="","",VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP($T$3,'Product Specifications'!A:AB,9,FALSE),Packaging!A:B,2,FALSE))

Comment: I presume this returns a cartoncode? Then you can just replace the A1 in the my formula with your equation. Or replace the A1 in my formula with  the cell reference your equationformula is in.

Comment: so I have a form I want to draw values from various worksheets based on a product dfitCA0004 and the corresponding dfitCE0004 for example but the first and last four values will be different for each product but each product has a CA and an EA.

Comment: Try replacing every `$T$3`  in your formula with `REPLACE($T$3,5,1,"e")` If that is not what you mean, than i,m lost.

Answer (score 0):

thank you the replace function works perfectly this is the final formula

```
=+IF($T$3="","",VLOOKUP(REPLACE($T$3,4,1,"e"),'Barcode Register'!A:E,5,FALSE))
```